# Export a class from a CoffeeScript file

Tags: class, node.js, export, coffeescript

If I have a CoffeeScript class defined in a separate file, which I'm calling from my main script, I can make the functions within the file globally visible, but not the class.

The included file is:

```
root = exports ? this

root.add = (a, b) ->

      return a + b

class root.userModel
      username: 'Aaaa'
      name: 'Bbbb'
```

I can access the function from my main code. How can I create the class?

Comment: I tried your code here and got no problem in accessing the class. If I call `u = new test.userModel()` then `u` will contain an object, as expected, and the object will be an instance of `test.userModel` (the file I used for testing is `test.coffee` and imported it with `test = require './test'`)

Comment: Thanks for your help everyone. Problem was due to a problem accessing the class in the main body of code

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code will indeed make `userModel` a global, assuming that `exports` is undefined and `this` is `window`. If you're having problems, check those conditions.

Answer (score 2):

The `class ...` form is an expression that returns a value. So, you'll want to assign the result of that `class` expression to a property on your export object. Like so:

```
root.userModel = class userModel
  username: 'Aaaa'
  name: 'Bbbb'
```

**Update:**

Oops, not true, should work fine either as `class root.userModel` or as `root.userModel = class userModel`.

Comment: That's not the case, `class root.userModel` compiles to ```root.userModel = (function() {
  function userModel() {... }
  return userModel;
})();
```

Comment: Yep, you're right. Was too quick on the response. It should work fine either way.

Comment: It would be better to remove the historical / incorrect information and submit an answer as if it was written today (the revision history contains the old versions). And remove all meta talk about past revisions, etc. (this can be put in comments and/or edit summaries).

Answer (score 2):

Just define your class with a '@' before its name:

```
class @ClassName
  blablabla: -> blablalblablabla
```