# Rails4: Use Coffeescript/javascript variable in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I'm trying to call a classed coffeescript/javascript function from my Rails 4 view code.  It's telling me that the class variable that was created on page load and used in document.ready doesn't exist anymore.

coffeescript:

```
class App
  reload_calendar: ->
    source = new Array
    viewable_calendars = $('input:checkbox:checked.visable_calendars').map(->
      @value
    ).get().join(',')
    calendar_url = '/events.json'
    new_event_link = '#{new_event_path}'
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar
      dayClick: (date, allDay, jsEvent, view) ->
        document.location.href = new_event_link + '?start_date=' + date
        return
      header:
        left: 'prev,today,next'
        center: 'title'
        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
      selectable: true
      selectHelper: true
      editable: false
      ignoreTimezone: false
      select: @select
      eventClick: @eventClick
      eventDrop: @eventDropOrResize
      eventSources: [ {
        url: calendar_url
        data:
          custom_param1: 'something'
          custom_param2: 'somethingelse'
        error: ->
          alert 'there was an error while fetching events!'
          return
      } ]
      eventResize: @eventDropOrResize
      timeFormat: 'h:mmtt{ - h:mmtt} '
    return

app = new App
$(document).ready ->
  app.reload_calendar()
  $('#calendar-color').minicolors()
```

partial:

```
<ul>
<% @calendars.each do |c| %>
  <li>
    <span style="background-color: <%= c.color %>;">
      <%= check_box_tag 'show_calendar_'+c.id.to_s, value=c.id.to_s, checked=true, :onchange => "app.reload_calendar()", :class => "visible_calendars" %>
    </span>
    <%= c.name %>
    <%= link_to 'x', calendar_path(c), :confirm => "Are you sure you want to remove the calendar?", :method => :delete %></li>
<% end %>
```

This loads the calendar fine (using app.reload_calendar at the end of the coffeescript), but fails with the error `Uncaught ReferenceError: app is not defined` when it's triggered by clicking or unclicking a check_box.

Comment: do you try `window.app = new App`?

Comment: Thanks, that worked. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

window.app = new App works, as Long Dương posted in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Just use this pattern for each coffescript class

```
class MyClass
  ...

root = exports ? window
root.MyClass = MyClass
```

Some other ways to make your class public [here](http://jarrettmeyer.com/blog/2013/02/07/getting-to-global-variables-in-coffeescript), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7533191/export-a-class-from-a-coffeescript-file)